# Matlab 2022b can not find cmake installation

Tags: matlab, cmake, ros2

I am trying to execute `ros2genmsg` command in matlab, by providing a `folderPath` as stated in the official documentation https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ros/ref/ros2genmsg.html in this link. Although I have installed `cmake` version `3.27.7` as stated in the terminal, I keep getting the following error: `Unable to find CMake in your system. Please install CMake version 3.15.5or higher and rerun the command` . I reruned the command but I keep getting the error. Whta can I do about it?

I am using mac and matlab 2022_b version.

What I finally found out is that I had to download CMake manually from the web and then include the path of the installation file to my matlab file like this :

```
oldPath = getenv('PATH');
newPath = strcat(oldPath, pathsep, '/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin'); % on Mac
setenv('PATH', newPath);
% Then try rosgenmsg
```

Comment: Do you have MATLAB Coder installed? Looks like this post shows the same issue and a couple of solutions: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1973764-matlab-r2022b-and-r2023a-installation-did-not-contain-cmake